# Entity Framework - Duplicating Record on Child Table

Tags: entity-framework

I am studying EF6 Please could you help me understand why EF6 are duplicating records in child table ?

1. Code:
   [Code Snipet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMj8M.png)
2. Database:
   [New Records created on DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saxdC.png)

Why EF6 created other lines and did not use StandardId = 6 ?

Regards

Comment: What version of EF?  What's the status of the Standard in the Change Tracker?  If it's `Added` then EF will insert a new row.  And if the ID is configured to be generated on the server, it will be inserted with a new ID.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], specifically the part that says "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question."

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.